# Enable Cors on WordPress

Tags: php, reactjs, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site with WordPress using WooCommerce, that I want to make as api for my React app..

I have understand that I need to add some Code Lines at the server code (wp content).
But I didn't understand which is code in which file of the server??

I have seen a lot of functions that "I need to put in my Functions.php" but none of them take care of the problem..

Someone can help me?
what is the missing code?
where do I paste it?
What I do wrong?

[The files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w7Fo.png)

Comment: Pretty sure there is a WP plugin to handle CORS

Comment: I tried the 2 wp plugins but still the same problem..